# All the buttons will modify the last user in piwebio python

Tags: python, for-loop, io

I'm playing arround with python and piwebio. I am trying to make a menu using a loop to show all my users and buttons to edit them. What my code it doing is that all the buttons will modify the last user in my json.

Lambda is overwriting it self, I just can't figure out how to get arround it.

```
        for item in users:
            with put_collapse('User: ' + item["user"]):
                put_buttons([item["user"]], onclick=[lambda *args, **kwargs: edit_nameoremail(item["user"],"name")])
                put_buttons(['Edit email: ' + item["email"]], onclick=[lambda *args, **kwargs: edit_nameoremail(item["user"],"email")])
                put_buttons(['Test email'], onclick=[lambda *args, **kwargs: sendmail(item["email"])])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it.
Not sure how to do with lambda, but it does work well with partial

```
from functool import partial
  for item in users:
            with put_collapse('User: ' + item["user"]):
                put_buttons([item["user"]], onclick= partial(edit_nameoremail, email_name="name",user_name=item["user"]))
                put_buttons(['Edit email: ' + item["email"]], onclick=partial(edit_nameoremail, email_name="email",user_name=item["user"]))
                put_buttons(['Test email'], onclick=partial(sendmail, recieve=item["email"]))
```